# How to render text as html in render message attachment in kendo chat in asp.mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, chatbot, kendo-ui-mvc

I am using **kendo.ui.Chat** api in ***asp.net mvc*** and i want to render the text feature in **renderMessage**  method as HTML, which is not rendering right now.

***Input :***

```
chat.renderMessage(
                      {
                        type: "text",
                        text: "<h1> Hello </h1>",
                       },
                        userInfo
                  );
```

***Output :***

```
<h1> Hello </h1>
```

But I need output as : **Hello**

Comment: Did you ever find a way of doing this?

Comment: @tony I had the same issue. Spent an hour and got it resolved. Please do check the below answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You might have to make use of template for html tags to work.

Example

```
<script id="custom-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
   <div class="#=styles.message#">
      <time class="k-message-time">#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(timestamp), "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") #</time>
    <div class="k-chat-bubble">#=text#</div>
  </div>
</script>
```

And

```
<script>
      var CUSTOM_TEMPLATE = kendo.template($('#custom-template').html());
      kendo.chat.registerTemplate("custom", CUSTOM_TEMPLATE);     

      var chat = $("#chat").kendoChat().data("kendoChat");  

      chat.renderMessage({
        type: "custom",
        text: "<h1>How may I help you</h1>!!!"
      }, { name: "The other user" }); 

      chat.renderMessage({
        type: "custom",
        text: "Help me find John Doe"
      }, chat.getUser()); 

</script>
```

References : https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/chat/methods/rendermessage